# Check if JSON string contains value and return associated properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array where every entry is a car name and I have a json object/string that contains those same car names followed by colour properties.

How can I check for each car in the array whether it is contained in the JSON string and return the colours associated with it one after another? Thanks very much for any help!

My code is like this:

```
var allCars;
var inputCount = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('cars.json', function(data) {
    console.log (data);
    allCars = data;

    createInputField();

    $('form').submit(function(){
        getCarColours()
    });

    })
}
);

function createInputField()
{           
$('.button').before('<select id="cars'+ inputCount +'" name="cars'+ inputCount +'" class="cars"></select> - <select id="percentage'+ inputCount +'" name="percentage'+ inputCount +'" class="percentage"></select><br />');             

$('.cars').append('<option value="'+ 0 +'">Please select a country </option>');
for (var i = 0; i < allcars.cars.length; i++) {
    $('.cars').append('<option value="'+ allcars.cars[i].name +'">'+ allcars.cars[i].name +'</option>');            
}

inputCount += 1
}


function getCarColours(){

var carsSelected = [];

for( var y = 1; y < inputCount; y++){
    carsSelected.push($('select[name="cars'+ y +'"]').val());
}

for (var i = 0; i < allcars.cars.length; i++) {
        if allcars.cars.has(carsSelected[i]{
            console.log(carsSelected[i]);
        }
}   
}
```

My JSON document looks like this:

```
{
"cars" : 
    [
        {
            "name": "Merc",
            "colour" : [
                {"name":"green", "percent":35, "rgb":"rgb(0,153,0)"}, 
                {"name":"red", "percent":31, "rgb":"rgb(191,0,0)"}, 
                {"name":"black", "percent":32, "rgb":"rgb(0,0,0)"},
                {"name":"white", "percent":2, "rgb":"rgb(255,255,255)"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BMW",
            "colour" : [
                {"name":"red", "percent":90, "rgb":"rgb(216,17,38)"}, 
                {"name":"black", "percent":10, "rgb":"rgb(0,0,0)"}
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like so

```
$.each(carsSelected, function(index,carName){
   var availableColors = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; ++i){ 
      if(cars[i].name == carName){
         availableColors = cars[i].colour;
         break;
      }
   }
  //at this point availableColors will either be empty if no match is found or have the associated color
});
```

Answer (score 3):

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JD9Ea/4) for **working** example

Some missing parenthesis in `getCarColours()` see fix below:

```
function getCarColours(){
    var carsSelected = [];
    for( var y = 1; y < inputCount; y++){
        carsSelected.push($('select[name="cars'+ y +'"]').val());
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            if (allCars.cars.has(carsSelected[i])){
                console.log(carsSelected[i]);
            }
    }
}
```

also your `createInputField()` is referring to the `allcars` variable instead of the global `alLCars`.

```
function createInputField()
{           
    $('.button').before('<select id="cars'+ inputCount +'" name="cars'+ inputCount +'" class="cars"></select> - <select id="percentage'+ inputCount +'" name="percentage'+ inputCount +'" class="percentage"></select><br />');             

    $('.cars').append('<option value="'+ 0 +'">Please select a country </option>');
    for (var i = 0; i < allCars.cars.length; i++) {
        $('.cars').append('<option value="'+ allCars.cars[i].name +'">'+ allCars.cars[i].name +'</option>');            
    }

    inputCount += 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks - hadn't noticed the missing parenthesis - the allCars variable is global so I don't think that's stopping anything working - any suggestion on how I can check if each car is in allCars.cars? Apparently the 'has' method doesn't exist for my object.

Comment: @db579 Ah yes I see. Do notice though that in your `createInputField()` you are referring to `allcars` with a lowercase 'c' instead of the global variable `allCars`. The same is true for getCarColours. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with some changes. Do you also want that percentage select menu populated from the json?

Comment: Thanks - I think I've actually got user814628's answer to work - just need some regex for the strings I think